# Flutter error: Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, keychain, codesign

I upgraded my Macbook OS with Sonoma OS, and tried building my flutter app for ios. I'm getting an error that the app was unable to sign my app with codesign.

Error: `Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign`

I've tried this with all my flutter apps, and all display the same error. I had to allow building of the app along with the error, and then build it again on Xcode to be able to publish it. I'm unable to debug or build the app, and I've tried most of the methods recommended online.

I tried upgrading Flutter.
I tried upgrading my OS to the latest version.
I tried removing my certificates in Keychain, and then re-downloading them on Xcode.
I have also tried renaming my Flutter Project folder.

The only thing that worked was moving the project out of my iCloud folder, and to an offline folder. This also only worked when the `flutter build ios` command opened a repetitive popup asking me to enter my login details for keychain/certificate. I remembered this popup in Xcode, and had to click on Always Allow, although this was not being shown via the Flutter command-line `flutter build ios` command while completing building.

Please could anyone suggest how to invoke the codesign login again for a project? I guess that the new OS/ new Xcode doesn't allow my older setup to build the app, and I might need to re-sign my project with always-allow-login popup.

Thanks!

[image: Codesign Error]